# Why does a "T" icon appear in Delphi's "Search for Usages" dialog?

Tags: delphi, refactoring, delphi-2009, icons

Instead of the normal IDE application icon, Delphi 2009 shows a small icon with a "T" in the "Search for Usages" dialog (see image below). What does this symbol mean?

[alt text http://www.mikejustin.com/images/littlet.png](http://www.mikejustin.com/images/littlet.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modeling surface in Delphi showed up after Borland acquired [Together](http://www.borland.com/us/products/together/index.html).

This is an Icon that has been used for Together.